# AngularJs Push into a child table of a child table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Jsonresult that looks like this.

```
[{
"comP_ID": 9,
"fileNum": "T2015",
"croRoute_DT": "2016-03-30T00:00:00",
"checklisTs": [],
"assoC_INC_OFFs": [{
    "aiO_ID": 14,
    "comP_ID": 9,
    "ofcnum": 1,
    "linK_TYPE": "Officer",
    "allegatioNs": [{
        "alleG_ID": 33,
        "iabAllegation": "allegation1",
        "disciplinedetaiLs": [{
            "disciplineDetail_ID": 9,
            "penalty": null

        }, {
            "disciplineDetail_ID": 10,
            "penalty": null

        }]
    }, {
        "alleG_ID": 59,
        "iabAllegation": "allegation12",
        "disciplinedetaiLs": []
    }, {
        "alleG_ID": 1061,
        "iabAllegation": null,
        "disciplinedetaiLs": []
    }],
    "officerinvolveDs": null
}, {
    "aiO_ID": 55,
    "comP_ID": 9,
    "ofcnum": 1,
    "linK_TYPE": "Officer",
    "allegatioNs": [{
        "alleG_ID": 27,
        "iabAllegation": "allegation11",
        "disciplinedetaiLs": []
    }, {
        "alleG_ID": 51,
        "iabAllegation": "allegation2",
        "disciplinedetaiLs": []
    }, {
        "alleG_ID": 1056,
        "iabAllegation": "allegation3",
        "disciplinedetaiLs": []
    }, {
        "alleG_ID": 60,
        "iabAllegation": null,
        "disciplinedetaiLs": []
    }],
    "officerinvolveDs": null
}, {
    "aiO_ID": 56,
    "comP_ID": 9,
    "ofcnum": 2,
    "linK_TYPE": "Officer",
    "allegatioNs": [{
        "alleG_ID": 28,
        "iabAllegation": "allegation11",
        "disciplinedetaiLs": []
    }, {
        "alleG_ID": 29,
        "iabAllegation": "allegation2",
        "disciplinedetaiLs": []
    }],
    "officerinvolveDs": null
}]
}]
```

I have setup all my api's accordingly and have been able to push data at the parent level and the child level but when I get to the child of the child level, I get a bad request error.

**What works**

```
$scope.comps.push(data);

$scope.comp.assoC_INC_OFFs.push(data);
```

But when I get to the allegatioNs table,I try a multiple ways and it won't work:

```
$scope.comp.assoC_INC_OFFs.allegatioNs.push(data);
```

Or

```
$scope.comp.assoC_INC_OFFs[0].allegatioNs.push(data);
```

My function to call comps:

```
getComp();
    function getComp() {
        Service.getComp()
        .success(function (comp) {
            $scope.comps = []
            $scope.comps = comp;
            $scope.index = 0;
            $scope.comp = $scope.comps[0];
}
```

My function to add:

```
$scope.updateAlleg = function (alleG_ID) {
                var id = alleG_ID;
                $http.post('/crams/api/aio/' + id + '/allegs', $scope.comp.assoC_INC_OFFs.allegatioNs).success(function (data) {
                    //console.log("updated Successfully!!");
                    $scope.comp.assoC_INC_OFFs.allegatioNs.push(data);
                    $scope.loading = false;
                }).error(function (data) {
                    $scope.error = "An Error has occured while updated Customer! " + data;
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    alert('Did Not Save!');
                    console.log($scope.error);
                });
            };
```

My error says:

> ModelState is Invalid'

**Question**
Can someone please help me figure out what the right way to push data into the allegations table?

Answer (score 0):

How is your `$scope.comps` populated ?

I don't know how you receive/parse the data but it's working fine on my end :

```
var comps = JSON.parse('[{"comP_ID":9,"fileNum":"T2015","croRoute_DT":"2016-03-30T00:00:00","checklisTs":[],"assoC_INC_OFFs":[{"aiO_ID":14,"comP_ID":9,"ofcnum":1,"linK_TYPE":"Officer","allegatioNs":[{"alleG_ID":33,"iabAllegation":"allegation1","disciplinedetaiLs":[{"disciplineDetail_ID":9,"penalty":null},{"disciplineDetail_ID":10,"penalty":null}]},{"alleG_ID":59,"iabAllegation":"allegation12","disciplinedetaiLs":[]},{"alleG_ID":1061,"iabAllegation":null,"disciplinedetaiLs":[]}],"officerinvolveDs":null},{"aiO_ID":55,"comP_ID":9,"ofcnum":1,"linK_TYPE":"Officer","allegatioNs":[{"alleG_ID":27,"iabAllegation":"allegation11","disciplinedetaiLs":[]},{"alleG_ID":51,"iabAllegation":"allegation2","disciplinedetaiLs":[]},{"alleG_ID":1056,"iabAllegation":"allegation3","disciplinedetaiLs":[]},{"alleG_ID":60,"iabAllegation":null,"disciplinedetaiLs":[]}],"officerinvolveDs":null},{"aiO_ID":56,"comP_ID":9,"ofcnum":2,"linK_TYPE":"Officer","allegatioNs":[{"alleG_ID":28,"iabAllegation":"allegation11","disciplinedetaiLs":[]},{"alleG_ID":29,"iabAllegation":"allegation2","disciplinedetaiLs":[]}],"officerinvolveDs":null}]}]');
console.log('before push', comps[0].assoC_INC_OFFs);
comps[0].assoC_INC_OFFs.push({'data' : 'somedata'});
console.log('after push', comps[0].assoC_INC_OFFs);
```

result :

```
before push [Object, Object, Object]
after push [Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/DFJUNIXVro8BVgQqm0nb?p=preview

Comment: Well, I have a $scope.comps, then I have a $scope.comp, $scope.comp = $scope.comps[index].

Comment: It would help understand the problem if you posted the parts where `$scope.comps` is populated (from API call I presume)

Comment: Yes, from an API. I have added my comps call to my question, hopefully that helps.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, could you please add a `console.log('comps', $scope.comps);` right after the `$scope.comps` is assigned from the API result and paste the output ? Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your time. It returns 8 arrays with objects in them.  It's pretty long so I pasted it into a plnker file https://plnkr.co/edit/m4ZRfjxuMjhIuy2tuDQz?p=preview

Comment: I updated the plunkr with the data you provided and still see no problem at all ... Have you tried to catch any errors from the API Call ? I would replace that `success` call to `then` and try to catch any error using `catch`. Try logging everything and see if there's anything wrong. My guess would be that the API call does not go all well

Comment: What if my api is creating it fine through postman and fun i use a angular modal it creates it just fine too? I'm not using the comps through the modal though.

Comment: Is there any chance your API is reachable from the web ?

Comment: Not functional to the test database but, I can paste it if that helps? Or maybe I can upload my project to GitHub? I'll be into work about 1 hour.

Comment: Also, if you'd like to work this off on the side I would like to compensate you for your time? I was going to go to pluralsight mentor and pay if I couldn't figure it out here! I have 1 other question as well. ;)

Comment: Hi again, I was wondering, why does your push not include the allegatioN's table?

Comment: It's working as well `comps[0].assoC_INC_OFFs[0].allegatioNs.push({'data': 'someotherdata'});`